# SCP didn't work in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, scp, jenkins-plugins

When I use the following codes in `terminal`, it works well.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn scp /Users/Shared/Jenkins/workspace/testslave/XXXXXX aaa@10.XXX.XXX.XX:/tmp/XXXX
expect "*assword:"
send "password\r"
interact
```

but when I copy the content to the `Jenkins`,the Jenkins didn't copy the file to the `destination`,and with no error.

Comment: You should paste the console log in here

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner approach is to generate a public/private key with no pass-phrase and to use it as an authentication method.

The steps are:

1. Generate the key by executing ssh-keygen
2. Copy the public key (usually id_rsa.pub) to the .ssh folder of the user in the destination host. In your case it seems to be /Users/Shared/Jenkins/.ssh
3. Execute: `scp -i id_rsa /Users/Shared/Jenkins/workspace/testslave/XXXXXX aaa@10.XXX.XXX.XX:/tmp/XXXX`